# Warehouse theme, Prestashop - Elementor Module

Tags: prestashop, elementor

I have Warehouse theme, prestashop 1.7.8.2.
I added an extended product description with elementor, but it is not showing at all at the product. Does anyone know, how to repair this?

Comment: Please contact the theme developer with your issue. No one from the community can help you with the information you provide.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.